# Strict aliasing and references to compile-time C arrays

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

Given the following code

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "A byte does not consist of 8 bits");

void func1(const int32_t& i)
{
    const unsigned char* j = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&i);
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(j[k]) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void func2(const int32_t& i)
{
    const unsigned char (&j)[4] = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char (&)[4]>(i);
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(j[k]) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    func1(-1);
    func2(-1);
}
```

From the language rules it is clear that `func1` is fine, as pointers to `unsigned char` can alias any other type. My question is: does this extend to C++ references to C-arrays with known length? Intuitively I would say yes. Is `func2` well-defined or does it trigger undefined behavior?

I have tried compiling the above code using Clang and GCC with every possible combination of `-Wextra -Wall -Wpedantic` and UBSAN, and have gotten no warnings and always the same output. That obviously doesn't state that there's no UB, but I couldn't trigger any of the usual strict-aliasing type optimization bugs.

Comment: My guess (and I daren't post this as an answer) is that there is no UB ***provided that*** the definition of `int32_t` is valid. That is, so long as this is a 4-byte (i.e. 4 char) **contiguous** chunk of memory, there's no problem.

Comment: which is why I used `int32_t` and not just `int` (because that might open up questions about cases in which `sizeof(int) != 4`, like on DOS etc.)

Comment: @Adrian [**7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types** from the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1) is relevant:  "The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a two's complement representation."  If `int32_t` exists, it seems it would have to be contiguous.  A "byte" could still be 8, 16, or 32 bits in this case, though.

Comment: @JonasMüller but sizeof(int32_t) is not necessarily 4 either because char is not necessarily 8 bits. Besides, sizeof(int32_t) is not a magic number unlike 4, so it's better to use that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed! Maybe I should not have used the term `byte`! But, will `char` always be 8 bits? Or, will `char` always be the same size as "byte?"

Comment: Ok, amended the code example to enforce 8-bits-in-a-`unsigned char`

Comment: @Adrian `CHAR_BIT` is required to be greater than or equal to `8` so no, it doesn't always have to be `8`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` though is guaranteed to always be `1`.

Comment: @NathanOliver So does that mean `sizeof(int32_t)` (if such a type exists) will always be 4?

Comment: @Adrian No.  `int32_t` is gauranteed to be 32 bits wide, but it's size will be `32 / CHAR_BIT` so it could be it's size will be in the range `[4, 1]`

Comment: Not in this example, because the `static_assert` checks that.

Comment: Yes, in this example it is fine, but generically the size will be in the range `[4, 1]`

Comment: @JonasMüller From the discussion, I can see why you have the "Language Liar" tag!

Comment: Maybe this is a better assertion: `static_assert(sizeof(int32_t) == 4, "Wrong size for 32-bit integer!");`?

Comment: @JonasMüller: *"From the language rules it is clear that `func1` is fine"*. In fact, not completely, `j[0]` would be fine, `j + 1` is fine. but `j[1]` and `j[2]` are pedantically UB as `j` doesn't point on an **array** (contrary to `func2` :-) ).

Comment: @JonasMüller I guess one possible explaination I can think of why you get no warnings is that it might be compiler extensions that makes this OK.

Comment: @Jarod42 _"`j[0]` would be fine, `j + 1` is fine"_ Nothing of this is fine.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Could you clarify?

Comment: @Jarod42 [expr.add]/6

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: My point was *"An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose"* (but indeed, there are no char object neither, the exception for `char` in strict aliasing rule seems really useless).

Comment: @Jarod42 Even if there were a `char` object, `reinterpret_cast` doesn't give you a pointer to it. So you violate [expr.add]/6 anyway.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: With a char object, it seems equivalent to `char c; char* p= &c; p[0] = '*'; auto end_c = p + 1;` which is valid...

Comment: @Jarod42 `reinterpret_cast` can't make a pointer to `char` from a pointer to `int`. I mean pointer value, not type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined behavior.

On the meaning of `reinterpret_cast` here we have **[expr.reinterpret.cast]**

> [11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) A glvalue expression of type T1 can be cast to the type
>   “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer to T1” can be
>   explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a
>   reinterpret_­cast. The result refers to the same object as the source
>   glvalue, but with the specified type. [ Note: That is, for lvalues, a
>   reference cast reinterpret_­cast(x) has the same effect as the
>   conversion *reinterpret_­cast(&x) with the built-in & and *
>   operators (and similarly for reinterpret_­cast(x)).  — end note ]
>   No temporary is created, no copy is made, and constructors or
>   conversion functions are not called.

This tells us that the cast int `func2` is valid so long as `reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char (*)[4]>(&i)` is valid. No shock here. But the crux of the matter is that you may not get anything meaningful out of that pointer conversion. On that subject we have this over at **[basic.compound]**:

> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a standard-layout union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no
>     non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object
>     ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
>   address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
>   to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`. [ Note: An array object and its
>   first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have
>   the same address.  — end note ]

That's an exhaustive list of meaningful pointer conversions. So we are not permitted to obtain an array address like that, and as such it is not a valid array glvalue. Therefore the further use you make of the result of the cast is undefined.

Comment: _"Therefore any further use of the result of the cast is undefined."_ Not any. You can apply the address-of operator to the result of the cast or cast back to the original type. So there are at least 2 further  uses.